# Extjs 4 remote filter store smaller (<) bigger (>) than

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is it possible to remote filter smaller than and bigger than? I know how to handle this in php and mysql but I don't know how to set such a filter in a extjs 4 store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box with 4.1, no.

You will need to overwrite the responsible <s>provider</s> proxy for that cause currently only property-value pairs get submitted ([responsible function](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-method-encodeFilters)). The other point is that the [Ext.util.Filter](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Filter) don't support any comparator for remotesort at all. So you have to implement your own and ensure that the store don't support local filtering (cause that won't work).

As a workarround you can commit the smaller/bigger along with the value as encoded string and substract the it then on the serverside. This would just cause a local filter to get no results.

Comment: useful function but disappointed that this is not yet implemented by extjs :( but thx!

Comment: @Manuel The implementation is not that complicated... You just need to override the mentioned method and extend the filter by one value which the new function takes if it is defined and skip if it is not

Answer (score 0):

I usually override the Ext.data.proxy.Server, like this:

```js
// ext store remote filter missing operator fix
Ext.override(Ext.data.proxy.Server, {encodeFilters: function(filters) {
    var min = [],
        length = filters.length,
        i = 0;

    for (; i < length; i++) {
        if(filters[i].property && filters[i].value){
            min[i] = {
                operator: filters[i].operator,
                property: filters[i].property,
                value   : filters[i].value
            };
        }
    }
    return this.applyEncoding(min);
}});
```