# Store filter greater than or equal

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

I have a store containing scores.I need to filter out than score >10 and less than 3.
Is it possible to filter out data.
I tried:

```
    Ext.getStore('MyStore').clearFilter(true);
    var RStore = Ext.getStore('MyStore');
    RStore.filter('score', '2');
```

this is working.but it filters fields having score 2.
I need to the store data having score >10....

I saw a stack link it is not possible

[Extjs 4 remote filter store smaller (<) bigger (>) than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216588/extjs-4-remote-filter-store-smaller-bigger-than)

Pls help me to have this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    var store = Ext.getStore('MyStore');
    store.clearFilter(true);

    store.filterBy(function(record, id){
    if(record.get("score") < 3 || record.get("score") > 10){
      return true;
    }    
    return false;
}, this);
```

You can see this in demo here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1359

Comment: What are you assigning to the 'value' variable? It should be a string or a number.

Comment: I used for loop to access the different records that has the specified valu

Comment: That means your store is having no data which is satisfying the criteria. Console you store data and check.

Comment: I have changed one condition. Please try this again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40539/discussion-between-anand-gupta-and-almakki)

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own filter function.

Have a look at: 
[ExtJS-store-filterby](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this as well:

```
var RStore = Ext.getStore('MyStore');    
RStore.clearFilter(true);

RStore.filter([
     {filterFn: function(item) { return item.get("score") > 10 || item.get("score") < 3;     }}
]);
```

hope this helps.